# Bulk Insert(BCP) into SQL server VS Sqoop Export into Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, hadoop

Which one is better option among following options in-terms of speed and performance for the purpose of exporting data from hive/hdfs to sql server.

1) Using **Sqoop Export** facility to connect to RDBMS (SQL server) and export data directly.

2) Dump CSV file using HIVE using **INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY** command and then perform **BCP** ( or Bulk Insert Query) on those CSV files to put the data into SQL server database.

Or, 
Is there any other better option?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I use `bcp` whenever I can. It's from what I can tell the fastest way to shotgun data into a database and is configurable on a (somewhat) fine grain level.

Couple things to consider:

1. Use a staging table. No primary key, no indexes, just raw data.
2. Have a "consolidation" proc to move data around after loading.
3. Use a row size of about `5000` to start, but if performance is of utmost concern, then test.
4. Make sure you increase your timeout.